# using nls in R to fit a distribution to a model - constant error on multiple parameter estimate

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, nls

I have a distribution of data (x), which I need to fit with a two-species, or three-species model (essentially the sum of two gamma distributions) to find D (the diffusion coefficient).

A single-specie fit worked great on a dataset with an obvious single gamma distribution ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkWNT.png)):

```
single_species <- function(x, D) {(4/D)^4 * x^3 * exp(-4 * x/D) / 6}

n0 <- nls(x~single_species(x, D), data=df,
      start=list(D=7))

Formula: x ~ single_species(x, D)

# Parameters:
#  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# D     8.14      42.59    0.19     0.85
#
# Residual standard error: 9.96 on 339 degrees of freedom

# Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.56e-06
```

However, when a single-species does not fit the data well, indicating that there are more than one species present in the dataset (ie two or more diffusion coefficients), multiple species are defined by:

```
two_species <- function(x,D1,D2,A) ((A*(4/D1)^4 * x^3 * exp(-4 * x/D1))/ 6) + ((1-A) * (4/D2)^4 * x^3 * exp(-4 * x/D2) / 6)

three_species <- function(x,D1,D2,D3,A1,A2) ((A1*(4/D1)^4 * x^3 * exp(-4 * x/D1))/ 6) + (A2 * (4/D2)^4 * x^3 * exp(-4 * x/D2) / 6) + ((1-A1-A2) * (4/D3)^4 * x^3 * exp(-4 * x/D3) / 6)
```

Where A is the fraction of molecules that have D1 or D2 (or D3) (sum of A = 1)

However, when I use nls on this distribution [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9DCl.png) :

```
n0 <- nls(x~two_species(x,D1,D2,A), data=df,
      start=list(D1=0.5,D2=2,A=0.5), algorithm="port", lower=c(0,0,0), upper=c(Inf,Inf,1))

n0 <- nls(x~three_species(x,D1,D2,D3,A1,A2), data=df,
          start=list(D1=0.3,D2=1,D3=3,A1=0.2,A2=0.4), algorithm="port", lower=c(0,0,0,0,0), upper=c(Inf,Inf,Inf,1,1))
```

I've tried various starting values and constantly get a whole lot of error messages including:

- Convergence failure: singular convergence (7) number of iterations
- exceeded maximum of 50
- step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562

I have tried nls2, log of both sides of the formula with lm, all to no result.

A1 should always be A1 < A2 < A3

Any help with this would be highly appreciated!

my dataset:

```
x
0.235628
17.8751
0.92881
1.33852
0.776867
0.228203
4.84179
1.22057
0.548748
1.05836
2.01539
2.74223
8.79386
4.66654
1.62801
6.47856
0.453273
1.95721
3.06736
3.92829
1.1674
2.71636
7.62454
9.54522
1.68041
6.91739
4.68201
7.16209
6.28874
0.424469
0.550265
0.133626
2.7604
1.57264
0.476539
0.799786
8.25841
0.818216
3.02923
0.845283
1.23313
0.94307
5.51206
4.10762
7.92469
0.501618
6.74433
1.87981
1.51518
1.10574
1.62274
2.61145
1.13505
2.15115
0.948538
0.575786
3.96403
1.13391
2.67401
4.8932
7.69174
1.60469
9.41733
3.92973
4.43847
4.5172
1.30444
1.75623
3.74461
6.24074
1.68499
1.28576
0.549821
0.327004
2.24318
1.92782
14.4288
3.913
3.90905
0.735655
0.788581
0.402483
1.74111
6.11239
0.555551
2.50481
5.94986
0.605481
2.30439
5.1826
0.797698
0.781417
0.235787
2.75223
0.765795
1.06081
2.09595
1.18545
3.87974
3.69264
5.24671
11.9989
4.13137
0.377252
0.38075
0.45152
0.0715022
1.71302
4.74751
0.448813
0.368998
5.65516
2.74724
1.66625
8.96428
0.57032
0.544007
14.6614
1.00987
0.751435
1.13095
0.825375
0.0915251
0.0307029
7.57248
2.19654
6.64205
5.8283
0.546514
1.54262
4.59642
2.26886
0.313481
0.899401
2.0872
4.61581
0.125168
1.00339
0.667833
1.79764
1.80171
1.71519
1.39723
2.23329
2.35602
1.374
0.638888
3.63688
0.190764
1.13048
0.759555
0.787464
0.283467
6.79304
1.61759
1.03545
1.12316
3.4562
1.52611
2.60332
0.666123
0.124695
1.82621
3.26061
8.9418
0.631927
2.86306
1.29449
0.881833
0.275634
0.232945
0.352353
3.1522
0.209823
0.0879465
3.36379
0.924595
7.74218
3.69087
0.65197
17.8039
0.394986
1.05359
1.18692
0.596482
0.979461
5.98717
0.760474
0.645782
3.41454
0.889993
2.10695
0.688352
4.51498
1.00767
1.38896
0.336251
0.280855
0.707932
1.85829
1.55989
0.964346
1.44273
3.03213
2.80219
0.621689
0.138351
2.79416
9.82785
0.346336
2.32438
0.323821
0.408156
1.82539
2.32621
2.49022
1.08678
0.565132
5.17033
1.2582
1.64266
0.320785
4.76515
4.15727
0.195925
0.237905
0.139768
1.68327
6.42137
0.270659
0.381643
2.7671
0.640868
1.18572
0.599123
2.52191
2.09277
2.56067
2.57177
1.43076
0.388851
1.43338
2.06796
1.24396
0.691589
1.55218
1.99634
2.84269
0.315898
5.57457
0.425725
6.85596
1.04252
1.92378
3.98717
2.70284
0.45887
0.253853
2.72678
0.896788
4.31086
0.314042
2.73825
0.482244
0.973264
0.363894
1.59072
0.138393
4.02704
3.48863
2.86681
0.254981
20.5295
7.05656
0.651843
5.53886
1.16387
1.77891
7.79789
2.08457
4.01589
3.52694
6.33575
11.9469
1.77768
10.9405
5.79783
4.01799
3.27923
1.62336
0.253849
3.17016
5.6346
5.72218
0.212156
8.71303
0.604521
0.393928
0.951299
0.105535
1.97456
0.228645
0.0885993
0.970614
0.331797
0.8882
0.207125
5.96139
4.30901
2.67052
6.06427
1.78677
1.86704
0.204199
1.36499
0.398699
5.50823
6.0943
2.88304
3.16451
28.1835
6.57267
4.84117
6.66626
0.673354
2.46893
0.926101
0.391776
1.49426
1.43271
0.55552
10.5488
1.1027
0.0242608
0.26997
5.02434
7.28681
0.715119
11.3462
0.834238
1.45658
0.220489
0.481341
0.42052
0.947293
0.123089
3.46748
0.80825
1.67787
3.14791
2.86301
2.28034
1.15433
5.74692
1.05893
3.5885
7.25132
14.2405
3.25385
0.19322
0.299582
0.20913
4.76666
0.409547
5.87122
1.8947
0.903698
6.0967
0.404751
1.11432
3.78539
0.251672
2.67964
1.40312
5.13765
0.768507
1.60216
5.73058
0.144853
3.19391
0.250119
25.9565
1.36489
1.60724
5.82343
7.01421
1.27405
2.85042
0.617026
0.825133
0.259929
0.713962
1.94747
0.227271
0.911457
1.66773
0.362607
2.26689
1.72124
1.27774
2.38347
0.726621
11.4037
0.368343
0.268743
0.141371
3.36587
0.275233
0.234291
0.25516
0.378151
0.0890815
1.39858
6.86048
0.917541
8.57514
1.59667
3.83732
1.08514
2.61907
4.20002
2.79285
0.507087
0.869388
0.353866
1.21622
1.0193
2.65375
9.13178
0.373336
1.21296
0.277867
1.43925
18.2431
5.3267
1.22623
0.290197
2.5665
1.84066
0.242302
0.689391
0.818641
4.15287
5.09324
1.90507
2.03613
0.0339691
9.35353
1.897
3.64994
1.65244
1.75804
6.41586
3.07865
1.90657
2.68342
2.46506
0.227236
2.55244
1.20504
0.5035
0.0984938
0.648093
0.173935
5.77877
0.127453
0.130114
1.1308
3.48069
7.51466
0.312899
7.33754
5.27583
3.42141
0.201144
6.07724
1.14909
2.12818
2.64009
2.71519
0.708705
5.8456
2.88334
0.0898487
1.9784
2.18765
0.922187
3.44737
1.83025
2.66275
1.32726
0.516081
0.851601
1.48596
2.79085
0.587694
0.409903
0.854892
0.284362
1.03647
16.1274
3.29025
2.4619
0.347376
0.340085
1.90168
27.1796
8.36123
5.32504
1.81772
0.483275
2.64287
0.470658
0.132246
1.04137
0.789034
0.195009
1.34178
0.217934
0.628853
0.563381
1.15051
10.5088
1.2465
0.283844
3.80743
0.132487
0.464928
1.03893
2.09554
0.53582
0.290795
0.0237878
0.71585
7.42139
0.103642
0.0542186
1.70494
0.810709
0.27513
0.300317
1.17462
2.38814
0.364667
3.11503
```

Comment: Try adjusting some of the `nls.control()` parameters.  I would start with increasing the tolerance to attempt to get some type of convergence.  Adjustments to min factor and max number of iterations are other options.